# Database Design: Common Foreign Keys to a Single Table

Tags: oop, database-design, foreign-keys

I am still new with database designing and I'm having a bit of difficulty with it.

I have a product table that has a main category and sub category attribute and I am having difficulties identifying a good design for the their database tables and class diagram.

An example would be an Orange's main_category would be "Fruit" and it's subcategory would be "pulpy fruit" and another product may be Broccoli and it's main_category would be "Vegetable" and it's subcategory would be "Fibrous Vegetables". So I believe subcategory is also under main_category where depending on the main_category selected, a list of subcategory can be chosen.

My current design is like this:

```
=======================       =======================       =====================
|        PRODUCT      |       |     SUBCATEGORY     |       |   MAIN CATEGORY   |
=======================       =======================       =====================
| PK       id         |       |PK         id        |       |PK       id        |
|         name        | --->  |          name       | --->  |        name       |
| FK main_category_id |       |FK main_category_id  |       =====================
| FK  subcategory_id  |       =======================                      ^
=======================  --------------------------------------------------|
```

But I'm having doubts with my current design and would like to ask for your opinions whether this design is acceptable or is there a better way of designing this.

Also, in terms of OOP, what type of relationship would this be?

Comment: That is indeed too many columns in PRODUCT! Having the MAIN CATEGORY and SUBCATEGORY both in PRODUCT yields duplicate information because MAIN CATEGORY is fully dependent upon SUBCATEGORY. Now, removing `main_category_id`, how could you find the MAIN CATEGORY name for a given PRODUCT? Go go JOIN!

Comment: That being said, if there are ever more than main/sub categories a BOM/Hierarchy structure might be more appropriate.

Comment: I was relating to my class diagram design when I created my database design so does that mean that even though my Product Class has a main_category attribute, my Product table does not necessarily have to have it also?

Comment: That's correct. While I wouldn't have put included that as an immediate relation in my DB design / "UML" sketches (I would have included a dotted "relationship") line, it is just redundant information when materialized here.

Comment: Hi, so I decided to go with your approach and used JOIN instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since a sub category is also a category, you can have them all in a single table. You may have a design like this,

`Product(id, name)`

`Category(id, name)`

`ProductMaincategoryAssignments(productId, categoryId)`

`ProductSubcategoryAssignments(productId, categoryId)`

Here the **productId** and **categoryId** are foreign keys which are referencing to corresponding **id** in **Product** and **Category** tables.

Comment: This approach loses information between a category and a subcategory and allows a product to be part of a sub-category and a category that do not relate.

Comment: Exactly as pst said, there would be subcategories and main categories that may not be related to each other.

Comment: Oh. I just thought we can store all the categories and subcategories in one relation. So do we need to specify a relation between a category and its sub categories? Like a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: @sriyan SUBCATEGORY.main_category_id relates to MAIN CATEGORY in a N-1 relation.